# how to show one more item from top or bottom of visible area with scrollIntoView()?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I want to show two items when using `scrollIntoView()` with navigating buttons (up and down) to let the user know there are items to navigate, but the first and last items should have default behavior, So the user knows it is end of list.

I hope this image helps:
[image]

here is my code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.myList{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: gray;
    list-style: none;
}
button{
    width: 40px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.myList>*{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}

.focused{
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <ul class="myList">
      <li data-nav="0">Item 1</li>
      <li data-nav="1">Item 2</li>
      <li data-nav="2">Item 3</li>
      <li data-nav="3">Item 4</li>
      <li data-nav="4">Item 5</li>
      <li data-nav="5">Item 6</li>
      <li data-nav="6">Item 7</li>
    </ul>
    <button onclick="move(true)">UP</button>
    <button onclick="move(false)">down</button>
    
    <script>
        let nav = document.querySelectorAll("[data-nav]");
        nav.forEach(el=>{
            el.classList.remove("focused");
        })
        nav[0].classList.add("focused");

        let focusedIndex = 0;
        function move(dir){
            if(dir && focusedIndex > 0) focusedIndex--;
            else if(!dir && focusedIndex < 6) focusedIndex++;
            nav.forEach(elem =>{
                elem.classList.remove("focused");
            })
            nav[focusedIndex].classList.add("focused");
            nav[focusedIndex].scrollIntoView(true);
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need when **appear the previous element**

- if we click in **up button** and the **current index not the first element**, in this **statue** we need to **scroll to previous** element and **add focused class** to current element

```js
let nav = document.querySelectorAll("[data-nav]");
            nav.forEach((el) => {
                el.classList.remove("focused");
            });
            nav[0].classList.add("focused");

            let focusedIndex = 0;
            function move(dir) {
                if (dir && focusedIndex > 0) focusedIndex--;
                else if (!dir && focusedIndex < 6) focusedIndex++;
                nav.forEach((elem) => {
                    elem.classList.remove("focused");
                });
                /*
                check if we click in up button and will not arrive to last one
                [1] add foucs to current index
                [2] scroll to prev current index
                */
                if(dir && nav[focusedIndex].dataset.nav != 0) {
                    nav[focusedIndex].classList.add("focused");
                    nav[focusedIndex-1].scrollIntoView(true);
                }
                /*
                    if we click in down button dont do any thing differnt because we already can see 
                    another items or the first condition return flase because this already the 
                    first element
                */
                else {
                    nav[focusedIndex].classList.add("focused");
                    nav[focusedIndex].scrollIntoView(true);
                }

            }
```